# mount overlay fs gives error device /cow does not exist

Tags: mount, overlayfs

I am running kubuntu 20.04.
Looking with mount, with /proc/mounts, and with df shows that the system had used this command:

mount -t overlay /cow / -o lowerdir=/filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work

1.

if I use this command does not work, but error occurs:

special device "/cow" does not exist.

2.

indeed, "/cow" is not in dir /dev, and is nowhere in the directory tree.

3.

and the arguments to lowerdir, to upperdir, to workdir cannot be found in the dirtree or elswhere in the system.

/filesysten.squashfs can be found, but with any trials with overlay fs it is not accepted.

thus all the advices in internet regarding overlay fs cannot be applied.

Regards
Anton

Comment: Are you using an installed system? or a *live* system (where *copy-on-write* is expected)?

Comment: I am runnung kubuntu 20.04 from a bough USB stick as live OS.

Comment: The USB stick has 32 GB capacity, but for the overlayfs  only a small part of the 32 GB is avaiable.